# Calculating attack rating of an army with craft weapons

Tags: illyriad

What is the formula that determines how craft weapons affect the total attack of an army when commanders or troops are equipped with them?

Why do none of the online battle calculators take craft weapons into account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of data to take into account when calculating the attack/defence scores for a battle in Illy.

- Base scores of unit
- Modifiers for terrain
- Modifiers for time of day (can affect some equipment)
- Modifiers from commander
- Modifiers from equipment (not all troops in a unit may have the equipment)

Most of those are pretty straightforward but with equipment there are a large number of possible items and each of those may affect several parts of the total modifiers. Gathering all that info and getting it in a format that will be easily queried takes time. To the best of my knowledge not all the information has been easily available which is why none of the currently public calculators have taken the equipment into account.

Comment: To this mix we can add prestige bonuses.  Is there a known formula that, once we have all this data, turns it into total attack and defence ratings?